# send arraylist values and fetch that array value in php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to get the values from a php file.

I have a java file like this

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> al = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) 
{
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("names["+i+"]",String.valueOf(name.get(i))));

    System.out.println("arr is " +String.valueOf(name.get(i)+ "arrrr"+name.get(i)));
}
```

Here,  `name` is an ArrayList.

Now I want that name ArrayList to be sent to php and loop that array and insert into database

this is my php file

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","aaa","aa");
mysql_select_db("aa", $con);

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$arr[] = $_POST['names[]'];

foreach ($arr as $key) 
{
    $query="insert into Orders1(names) values('$key')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

it's inserting `""` (empty) value in database please help me.

Comment: Where is the problem? Either you have trouble sending stuff to PHP or you have problems using the values in PHP or MySQL. You cannot possible ask this question with both the Java and the MySQL tag. Narrow down the problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol i am android developer i want to send a arraylist value to php and insert it into db

Comment: PHP just gets a post request with a chunk of data. It doesn't care whether it's sent from Android using Java or with a html form from a Windows browser. Check if the input is okay. If not, fix the java, if it is, leave the whole Java part out of it (just mention it) and narrow down the problem to the part in PHP that goes wrong. If you cannot tell where it goes wrong, how could we?

Comment: the below answer solved my problem. any way @GolezTrol thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: and now you've deleted your php code, so the following won't make much sense...

---

If you're using array-based field names in your html form, e.g.

then the `[]` do **NOT** appear in the $_POST array when the form's submitted. Instead, `$_POST['foo']` becomes a sub-array of the various values entered into those form fields.

That means

```
$arr[] = $_POST['names[]'];
```

is almost certainly an undefined array key, returning a `NULL`, which you then append to the `$arr` array. You loop over $arr and insert the values, but insert only that null.

Try, simply:

```
foreach($_POST['names'] as $val) {
  $v = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  $sql = "ISNERT INTO .... VALUES ('$v');
}
```

note the use of the escape function. Your code is highly vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and would leave your server open to a total remote compromise.

Comment: but i have small question i have 1,2,3 in my arraylist but its inserting 3 2 1 in db why so ?

Comment: somewhere something's doing an unshift instead of a push on the array? no idea.

Comment: any ways thanks for your help answer accepted. by the way where are you from i am from INDIA, i have one more question what if i am sending two arrayslist to php file

Comment: i need to fetch two arraylist like this at the same time is it possible?

Comment: You can ask new questions as a new question. That allows you to add more explanation and others to add a bigger/better answer.